# Extracting sub-string after the first space in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need help in regex or Python to extract a substring from a set of string. The string consists of alphanumeric. I just want the substring that starts after the first space and ends before the last space like the example given below.

```
Example 1:

A:01 What is the date of the election ?
BK:02 How long is the river Nile ?    

Results:
What is the date of the election
How long is the river Nile
```

While I am at it, is there an easy way to extract strings before or after a certain character? For example, I want to extract the date or day like from a string like the ones given in Example 2.

```
Example 2: 

Date:30/4/2013
Day:Tuesday

Results:
30/4/2013 
Tuesday
```

I have actually read about regex but it's very alien to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend using `split`

```
>>> s="A:01 What is the date of the election ?"
>>> " ".join(s.split()[1:-1])
'What is the date of the election'
>>> s="BK:02 How long is the river Nile ?"
>>> " ".join(s.split()[1:-1])
'How long is the river Nile'
>>> s="Date:30/4/2013"
>>> s.split(":")[1:][0]
'30/4/2013'
>>> s="Day:Tuesday"
>>> s.split(":")[1:][0]
'Tuesday'
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code does exactly what I need without needing to use regex. I was trying regex with no luck.

Comment: I run some tests, partition was ~18.9% faster than split, and ~285% faster than a find based approach.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> s="A:01 What is the date of the election ?"
>>> s.split(" ", 1)[1].rsplit(" ", 1)[0]
'What is the date of the election'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to dig into regex if this is all you need; you can use `str.partition`

```
s = "A:01 What is the date of the election ?"
before,sep,after = s.partition(' ') # could be, eg, a ':' instead
```

If all you want is the last part, you can use `_` as a placeholder for 'don't care':

```
_,_,theReallyAwesomeDay = s.partition(':')
```

Comment: don't use `_`, just use `theReallyAwesomeDay = s.partition(':')[2]`

Comment: @gnibbler - I think that `_` is much clearer, especially since it's common to do `start,_,end = s.partition(':')` (so it makes sense to follow the same form for the end only)

Comment: It's also very common to use `_` as an alias for `gettext`